# Unity How to make a button one clickable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have a working unity quiz game (mobile) and everything works just fine except players can earn or lose points on every touch/click. I mean if the question is true and you spam the true button you will get 30 points (normally you can take 5) and button click sounds keep playing cuz you spam the button. So my question is how can I make a button oneshot?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `oneshot` as in interactable only after a single click, you would just need to change the intractability of your button after an `onclick` event. I am not sure how your current `onclick` is setup, but you would just need to set the [`interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) field to `false`, then set it back to `true` when you want them to be able to click it again.

```
public void YourOnClickHere(Button yourButton)
{
     yourButton.interactable = false;
}
```

As it seems you have multiple buttons and possibly other parameters you would want to send with each `onclick`, I would advise to assign the `onclick` in code in `Start`.

```
[SerializeField] private UnityEngine.UI.Button yourButton;

private void Start()
{
     yourButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate{YourOnClick(yourButton, otherData);});
}

private void YourOnClick(Button btn, OtherType otherParam)
{
    btn.interactable = false;
}
```

As I am not sure how your setup currently works as you did not provide it, you can use these snippets as a guide.